# R Shiny: How to change title of plot based on number of inputs selected in selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, selectinput

I have an app that I'd like to be able to have the title change once there is more than 1 input selected in a `selectizeInput`. I know this is a simple thing but I can't seem to figure it out!

**Sample of data:**

```
    criteriap<-structure(list(Year = c(1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 
1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 
1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 
1993, 1993, 1993, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
1994, 1994, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995), 
    State = c("NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
    "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
    "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
    "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
    "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
    "NJ", "NJ"), County = c("Hudson", "Camden", "Morris", "Bergen", 
    "Essex", "Union", "Essex", "Union", "Hudson", "Camden", "Morris", 
    "Bergen", "Essex", "Union", "Essex", "Union", "Hudson", "Camden", 
    "Morris", "Bergen", "Essex", "Union", "Essex", "Union", "Hudson", 
    "Camden", "Morris", "Bergen", "Essex", "Union", "Essex", 
    "Union", "Hudson", "Camden", "Morris", "Bergen", "Essex", 
    "Union", "Essex", "Union", "Mercer", "Middlesex", "Hudson", 
    "Camden", "Morris", "Bergen", "Essex", "Union", "Essex", 
    "Union"), Station_Name = c("Bayonne", "Camden Lab", "Chester", 
    "Cliffside Park", "East Orange", "Elizabeth Lab", "Newark Lab", 
    "Plainfield", "Bayonne", "Camden Lab", "Chester", "Cliffside Park", 
    "East Orange", "Elizabeth Lab", "Newark Lab", "Plainfield", 
    "Bayonne", "Camden Lab", "Chester", "Cliffside Park", "East Orange", 
    "Elizabeth Lab", "Newark Lab", "Plainfield", "Bayonne", "Camden Lab", 
    "Chester", "Cliffside Park", "East Orange", "Elizabeth Lab", 
    "Newark Lab", "Plainfield", "Bayonne", "Camden Lab", "Chester", 
    "Cliffside Park", "East Orange", "Elizabeth Lab", "Newark Lab", 
    "Plainfield", "Rider Univ", "Rutgers Univ", "Bayonne", "Camden Lab", 
    "Chester", "Cliffside Park", "East Orange", "Elizabeth Lab", 
    "Newark Lab", "Plainfield 2"), value = c(103, 82, 60, 97, 
    112, 112, 97, 74, 97, 78, 56, 96, 103, 94, 93, 75, 104, 78, 
    55, 89, 108, 120, 104, 72, 86, 71, 56, 83, 96, 90, 94, 74, 
    96, 85, 66, 88, 100, 116, 115, 79, 63, 82, 87, 82, 53, 82, 
    80, 92, 88, 79), pollutant = c("no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", 
    "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", 
    "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", 
    "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", 
    "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", 
    "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", "no2", 
    "no2")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

**Sample app**

```
    library(shiny)
    library(tidyverse)
    criteriap<-criteriap%>% 

  dplyr::filter(pollutant == "ozone")
        ui <- fluidPage(
          
          titlePanel("Criteria Air Pollutant Trends"),
          
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              selectInput("pollutant",label =em("Select Pollutant:",style="color:Navy;font-weight: bold;"),
                          choices = unique(criteriap$pollutant)),
              uiOutput("county"),
              uiOutput("station")),
            
            mainPanel(
              plotOutput("plot1")%>%
                withSpinner(type = 5, color = "blue")
            )
          )
        )
    
    server <- function(input, output,session) {
      
      ### Create reactive dataframe based on pollutant info ###
      datasub<-reactive({
        foo <- subset(criteriap, pollutant == input$pollutant)
        return(foo)
      })
      
      output$county<-renderUI({
        selectizeInput("county_input",label = strong("Select County:",style = "color:Navy;font-weight: bold;"),
                       choices = unique(datasub()$County),
                       selected = unique(datasub()$County[1]))})
      
      
      datasub2<-reactive({
        foo<-subset(datasub(),County == input$county_input)
      })
      
      
      output$station<-renderUI({
        selectizeInput("station_input",multiple = TRUE,label = strong("Select Station:",style = "color:Navy;font-weight: bold;"),
                       choices = unique(datasub2()$Station_Name),
                       selected = unique(datasub2()$Station_Name[1]))})
      
      
      datasub3<-reactive({
        foo<-subset(datasub2(),Station_Name %in% input$station_input)
        return(foo)
        
      })
      
      
      # This creates the plot 
      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        req(input$pollutant)
        req(input$station_input)
        if(input$pollutant == "ozone"){
          ggplot(data = datasub3(),aes(x=Year,y=value,color = datasub3()$Station_Name))+
            geom_line(size = 1.3)+
            ggtitle(paste0(datasub3()$Station_Name," Ozone Trend\n 4th-Highest Daily Maximum 8-Hour Concentration (ppm)",sep = "")) +
            ylab("Concentration, Parts per Million (ppm)") +
            scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0, 0.130),
                               labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.001,
                                                              decimal.mark = "."))+
            geom_segment(aes(x=1997,xend=2008,y=0.08,yend=0.08),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
            geom_segment(aes(x=2008,xend=2016,y=0.075,yend=0.075),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
            geom_segment(aes(x=2016,xend=2018,y=0.070,yend=0.070),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
            scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1990,2020,by=1))+
            annotate("text",
                     x = c(2002, 2011, 2017),
                     y = c(0.078, 0.059, 0.055),
                     label = c("1997 8-Hour NAAQS = 0.08 ppm",
                               "2008 8-Hour NAAQS = 0.075 ppm" , "2016 8-Hour\nNAAQS = 0.070 ppm"),
                     family = "", fontface = 3, size=4) 
        }
        
        else if(input$pollutant == "ozone" && length(input$station_name>1)){
          ggplot(data = datasub3(),aes(x=Year,y=value,color = datasub3()$Station_Name))+
            geom_line(size = 1.3)+
            ggtitle(input$County)+
            ylab("Concentration, Parts per Million (ppm)") +
            scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0, 0.130),
                               labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.001,
                                                              decimal.mark = "."))+
            geom_segment(aes(x=1997,xend=2008,y=0.08,yend=0.08),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
            geom_segment(aes(x=2008,xend=2016,y=0.075,yend=0.075),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
            geom_segment(aes(x=2016,xend=2018,y=0.070,yend=0.070),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
            scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1990,2020,by=1))+
            annotate("text",
                     x = c(2002, 2011, 2017),
                     y = c(0.078, 0.059, 0.055),
                     label = c("1997 8-Hour NAAQS = 0.08 ppm",
                               "2008 8-Hour NAAQS = 0.075 ppm" , "2016 8-Hour\nNAAQS = 0.070 ppm"),
                     family = "", fontface = 3, size=4) 
        }
      })}
    
    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I just want the plot's title to change to the county name when there is more then more input selected for the station.

Comment: Hi @NBE, instead of `ggtitle(input$County)` try `ggtitle(datasub3()$County)`

Comment: @Isa Thanks for your comment. I tried that but it didn't work:/

Comment: Sharing the code as answer which worked for me. You can check the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made slight changes in sample data and code:

```
criteriap <- structure(list(Year = c(1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 
                               1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 
                               1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 
                               1993, 1993, 1993, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
                               1994, 1994, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995), 
                      State = c("NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
                                "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
                                "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
                                "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
                                "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", 
                                "NJ", "NJ"), County = c("Hudson", "Camden", "Morris", "Bergen", 
                                                        "Essex", "Union", "Essex", "Union", "Hudson", "Camden", "Morris", 
                                                        "Bergen", "Essex", "Union", "Essex", "Union", "Hudson", "Camden", 
                                                        "Morris", "Bergen", "Essex", "Union", "Essex", "Union", "Hudson", 
                                                        "Camden", "Morris", "Bergen", "Essex", "Union", "Essex", 
                                                        "Union", "Hudson", "Camden", "Morris", "Bergen", "Essex", 
                                                        "Union", "Essex", "Union", "Mercer", "Middlesex", "Hudson", 
                                                        "Camden", "Morris", "Bergen", "Essex", "Union", "Essex", 
                                                        "Union"), Station_Name = c("Bayonne", "Camden Lab", "Chester", 
                                                                                   "Cliffside Park", "East Orange", "Elizabeth Lab", "Newark Lab", 
                                                                                   "Plainfield", "Bayonne", "Camden Lab", "Chester", "Cliffside Park", 
                                                                                   "East Orange", "Elizabeth Lab", "Newark Lab", "Plainfield", 
                                                                                   "Bayonne", "Camden Lab", "Chester", "Cliffside Park", "East Orange", 
                                                                                   "Elizabeth Lab", "Newark Lab", "Plainfield", "Bayonne", "Camden Lab", 
                                                                                   "Chester", "Cliffside Park", "East Orange", "Elizabeth Lab", 
                                                                                   "Newark Lab", "Plainfield", "Bayonne1", "Camden Lab1", "Chester", 
                                                                                   "Cliffside Park", "East Orange", "Elizabeth Lab", "Newark Lab", 
                                                                                   "Plainfield", "Rider Univ", "Rutgers Univ", "Bayonne1", "Camden Lab1", 
                                                                                   "Chester", "Cliffside Park", "East Orange", "Elizabeth Lab", 
                                                                                   "Newark Lab", "Plainfield 2"), value = c(103, 82, 60, 97, 
                                                                                                                            112, 112, 97, 74, 97, 78, 56, 96, 103, 94, 93, 75, 104, 78, 
                                                                                                                            55, 89, 108, 120, 104, 72, 86, 71, 56, 83, 96, 90, 94, 74, 
                                                                                                                            96, 85, 66, 88, 100, 116, 115, 79, 63, 82, 87, 82, 53, 82, 
                                                                                                                            80, 92, 88, 79), pollutant = c("ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", 
                                                                                                                                                           "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", 
                                                                                                                                                           "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", 
                                                                                                                                                           "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", 
                                                                                                                                                           "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", 
                                                                                                                                                           "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", "ozone", 
                                                                                                                                                           "ozone")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "data.frame"))

criteriap

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinycssloaders)

criteriap <- criteriap %>% 
  dplyr::filter(pollutant == "ozone")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Criteria Air Pollutant Trends"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("pollutant",label = em("Select Pollutant:",style="color:Navy;font-weight: bold;"),
              choices = unique(criteriap$pollutant)),
      uiOutput("county"),
      uiOutput("station")),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1") %>% 
        withSpinner(type = 5, color = "blue")
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ### Create reactive dataframe based on pollutant info ###
  datasub <- reactive({
    foo <- subset(criteriap, pollutant == input$pollutant)
    return(foo)
  })  
  output$county<-renderUI({
    selectizeInput("county_input", label = strong("Select County:",style = "color:Navy;font-weight: bold;"),
               choices = unique(datasub()$County),
               selected = unique(datasub()$County[1]))})
  datasub2<-reactive({
    foo <- subset(datasub(),County == input$county_input)
    return(foo)
  })  
  output$station<-renderUI({
    selectizeInput("station_input", multiple = TRUE, label = strong("Select Station:",style = "color:Navy;font-weight: bold;"),
               choices = unique(datasub2()$Station_Name),
               selected = unique(datasub2()$Station_Name[1]))})
  datasub3<-reactive({
    foo<-subset(datasub2(),Station_Name %in% input$station_input)
    return(foo)    
  })
  # This creates the plot 
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$pollutant)
    req(input$station_input)
    if(input$pollutant == "ozone" & length(input$station_input) == 1){
      ggplot(data = datasub3(),aes(x=Year,y=value,color = datasub3()$Station_Name))+
    geom_line(size = 1.3)+
    ggtitle(paste0(datasub3()$Station_Name," Ozone Trend\n 4th-Highest Daily Maximum 8-Hour Concentration (ppm)",sep = "")) +
    ylab("Concentration, Parts per Million (ppm)") +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0, 0.130),
                       labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.001,
                                                      decimal.mark = "."))+
    geom_segment(aes(x=1997,xend=2008,y=0.08,yend=0.08),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
    geom_segment(aes(x=2008,xend=2016,y=0.075,yend=0.075),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
    geom_segment(aes(x=2016,xend=2018,y=0.070,yend=0.070),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1990,2020,by=1))+
    annotate("text",
             x = c(2002, 2011, 2017),
             y = c(0.078, 0.059, 0.055),
             label = c("1997 8-Hour NAAQS = 0.08 ppm",
                       "2008 8-Hour NAAQS = 0.075 ppm" , "2016 8-Hour\nNAAQS = 0.070 ppm"), family = "", fontface = 3, size=4) 
} else if(input$pollutant == "ozone" & length(input$station_input)>1){
      ggplot(data = datasub3(),aes(x=Year,y=value,color = datasub3()$Station_Name))+
    geom_line(size = 1.3)+
    ggtitle(datasub3()$County)+
    ylab("Concentration, Parts per Million (ppm)") +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0, 0.130),
                       labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.001,
                                                      decimal.mark = "."))+
    geom_segment(aes(x=1997,xend=2008,y=0.08,yend=0.08),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
    geom_segment(aes(x=2008,xend=2016,y=0.075,yend=0.075),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
    geom_segment(aes(x=2016,xend=2018,y=0.070,yend=0.070),color="red",size =1.3,linetype = "dashed")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1990,2020,by=1))+
    annotate("text",
             x = c(2002, 2011, 2017),
             y = c(0.078, 0.059, 0.055),
             label = c("1997 8-Hour NAAQS = 0.08 ppm",
                       "2008 8-Hour NAAQS = 0.075 ppm" , "2016 8-Hour\nNAAQS = 0.070 ppm"), family = "", fontface = 3, size=4) 
    }
  })}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you mark the parts where you did your slight changes?

Comment: @Markus sorry for late reply. First change is in the data where pollutant was **no2** so I changed it to **ozone**. 
Changes in code are as follows: - 
`if(input$pollutant == "ozone" & length(input$station_input) == 1)`
`else if(input$pollutant == "ozone" & length(input$station_input)>1)`